# How to use Flow with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, flowtype

I'd like to use [Flow](https://flowtype.org) in Visual Studio 2015, but the syntax is not supported. Is it any extension or plugin for VS could help me?

[image: Flow support in Visual Studio]

Answer (score -1):

There are projects focusing on supporting FlowType in VSCode - the currently stable is https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode

You can in their README tips & known issues and it could help you with Visual Studio 2015 as well.

Comment: VSCode and Visual Studio has nothing in common except the name and the same vendor...